# Is there an 'alt' attribute for the <picture> tag? — Use case: picture element without <img src="">

Tags: html, image, accessibility, alt-attribute, picture-element

I am using `<picture>` tags. My target group uses modern browsers, so as soon as [Firefox supports WebP](https://liliputing.com/2019/01/firefox-65-adds-webp-image-av1-video-support.html) there is no need to use the `<img>` tag.

**Now:**

```
<picture>
    <source srcset="image-200px.webp 1x, image-400px.webp 2x" type="image/webp">    
    <img src="image-200px.jpg" alt="Description">
</picture>
```

**Soon:**

```
<picture>
    <source srcset="image-200px.webp 1x, image-400px.webp 2x">
</picture>
```

Is there a way to implement an `alt` attribute for `<picture>` when not using the `<img>` tag?

Comment: You can use img tag with srcste attribute. https://html.com/attributes/img-srcset/

Answer (score 12, accepted):

> My target group uses modern browsers so. As soon as Firefox support WebP there is no need to use the `<img>` tag

While you might not care about supporting browsers which do not support the `<picture>` element, [the HTML specification](https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/semantics-embedded-content.html#the-picture-element) says:

> **Content model**:
>
> Zero or more source elements, followed by one img element, optionally intermixed with script-supporting elements.

The `img` element is **mandatory**, so the alternative text is still provided by the `alt` attribute on the `img` element.

Comment: Good to know, thanks. Then I will go on using the `img` element within the `picture` element.

Answer (score -1):

The `<picture>` tag will fall back to the string written inside the tags, so if you write

```
<picture>
    <source srcset="image-200px.webp 1x, image-400px.webp 2x">
    Some description

</picture>
```

You will see the description if the browser doesn't support the tag or image is unavailable.

Comment: [A validator](https://validator.nu/) reports "Error: Text not allowed in element picture in this context." And [the spec](https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/semantics-embedded-content.html#the-picture-element) says: Zero or more source elements, followed by one img element, optionally intermixed with script-supporting elements.

Comment: Also, I suspect error recovery means that if the browser does support the element, but the user is using a screen reader, the invalid text will be ignored instead of being read out.